# Initial connection to Firebase seems fatally slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I've been developing an app that relies on its backend data being available almost immediately after opening. The app's home view is a table view controller that populates each of its cells with titles and then full cell background images. The titles come back quick enough as they are just strings but the images (of which im currently only loading 1-2 of them) on average take nearly 10-15 seconds. Also, when a user clicks one of these cells, this opens a collection view that has to load many more photos. I have been testing this with between 4 and 10 photos so far and it takes between 30 seconds and some times even minutes to pull these down. After these initial loads, it seems to be rather immediate when updates happen..even when several photos get added at once. This could be just the way Firebase stores to to a local copy of the Firebase on the device? Anyway, I was hoping someone could provide some insight as to why Firebase is loading this data so slowly. Is Firebase not capable of powering a photo heavy app? Or is the more likely user error of sorts holding me back?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Loading a large collection of photos from a JSON database is a non-ideal use-case. You're converting between base64 encoded string and a sequence of bytes needlessly. It's often better to use a dedicated file storage service such as Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage. This has been covered regularly recently, so I suggest you search and read. Aside from that, there is nothing we can answer without seeing a minimal reproduction of what you've done. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've gone through this exercise and those times seem excessively long. If every photo was 10MB on a slow connection maybe, but it sounds like something else is causing the issue. As @FrankvanPuffelen says, a picture storage company is one solution but have you considered thumbnails instead of full size images? Please post a code snippet and structure.